# How to handel if n/w is gone in betwwn

Tags: android

I am working on an application which uses internet on every Activity. I am checking the connection onCreate of every Activity. But if n/w(Internet) is gone in between how can i know. is there any Method which can notify whenever the Network has gone during Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in each `Activity` class you can add this broadcast receiver  in the onReceive method you can interact with the activity  this is an example

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(...) {
            ...
        }
   });

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");

        this.registerReceiver(this.receiver, filter);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        this.unregisterReceiver(this.receiver);
    }
}
```

this way the receiver is instantiated when the class is created (could also do in onCreate). Then in the onResume/onPause I handle registering and unregistering the receiver. Then in the reciever's onReceive method I do whatever is necessary to make the activity react the way I want to when it receives the broadcast.

Comment: But it will check the connection only when i will call this method. what i want is it can notify itself if network is gone.

Comment: try to use broadcast receiver  
<receiver android:name=".myBroadcastClass"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:priority = "0">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" /

                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>

Comment: could you please post this as a new Answer in place of Comment.?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` broadcast which you can listen to get the updates about the connection. Here are some more details http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ce1c3ed3e39a0c81

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not able to get this link due to Firewall or something like that.